# Getting the information of Dialed Numbers

Tags: android

I have an Activity which launches Dialer with specified number. After the user finishes the call, it will return to my activity. How should I get the information of the call that the user made. ie Call duration ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, check the call logs. You can easily access this. Do something like,

Define,
public Cursor mCallCursor;

Then define the fields you want to obtain from the call log,

```
public static final String[] STR_FIELDS = {
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE,
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE,
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL,android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER
        };
```

Set the order,
public static final String STR_ORDER = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";

Call the cursor.

```
mCallCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            STR_FIELDS,
            null,
            null,
            STR_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [CallLogs.Calls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html) class and [this tutorial](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/phonecalls.html). See if these help.